# Find required entities to accomplish specific task in shortest time

Tags: ai, path-finding, grid, state

I have a grid like map with entities that can perform turn-based actions like moving or growing strength. When I have a task that requires a certain strength, I want to find the entities required to solve that task as fast as possible and move them to the target.

The distance to the target is important, since moving a tile takes 1 turn. When entities move on a tile with an existing entity, their strength is combined together. A task can be solved only if the combined strength of the last entity is greater than the requirement. This logically means that entities near the target can grow while additional entities need to move to the target immediately.

It feels like I could use a modified pathfinding, but I can't formulate the procedure to get something meaningful. This inablity also worries me a bit that the problem might be np-hard.

Can you help me?

Comment: Could you define "entities required"? is it only the one having enough strength? is the distance to the action important? other considerations?

Comment: @AdrianMaire thanks, I did explain the problem a bit further

Comment: I guess I still miss what kind of "optimal" you are looking for. As I understand it now, you could just order entities by their distance to the target and take the first of the list up to accumulate enough strength.

Comment: See: [the A* search algorithm](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm)

Comment: I know A*, but I'm not sure how I can incorperate that entites nearer the target can grow while the ones in the back are moving.

Comment: @Krythic: you may escape SO special characters with \\.

Comment: Here's a related (simpler) problem: given jobs and given entities that can perform those jobs, and a cost for each entity to perform a job, what's the best choice of entity for each job? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_algorithm It's not the same as your problem, as it tries to assign exactly one entity for a job. I agree with Adrian that it's not clear what optimality you want, as you could order everyone to go there and work on the task.